# How to store a checklist with ordered items on the DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to store some checklists on a MySql DB. It's proving trickier than anticipated:

- There is a "master" checklist which applies to everything
- Each port will refer to the main checklist, BUT with extra items sprinkled in specific spots

My initial idea is to have a `checklists` table with fields:

- id
- description
- portId (null if it's an item in the "general" checklist)
- position

Here, the "master" checklist would be the items with "portId" set to null, and the port-specific checklists would be the ones with portId set to something.
However, ordering things is tricky at best: the "position" parameter is ambiguous, since it might refer to the position of the port-specific list, but reordering a "main" (non-port) item would mess things up badly.

Another option would be a linked list:

- id
- description
- portId (null if it's an item in the "general" checklist)
- previousId

This means that each item would know who the "parent" is.
This seems to be the perfect solution. However... there is a problem with querying: how do you write a query so that items come up in the right order? (that is, first the one without any id, then the first item with the first record as its father, and so on). Also, I am concerned about breaking the linked list if anything goes wrong.

Is there a "best practices" for such a problem?

Comment: What does "port" mean in this context?

Comment: Oh it's just the port (as in maritime port) the extra items will apply to. It's basically an ID that specifies that that particular item is not a "general" item,  but specific for that one port

Comment: Here I am, 20 years experience in development, and I just can't find the right way to approach this. Every time I think of a solution, I automatically dislike it...

Comment: `position` field usage is not clear - should it be numbered/ordered per portId? What's wrong with plain `select ... order by portId asc, position asc` in your first schema?

Comment: If you worry about linked list integrity you can replace it with or combine with nested set approach at the expense of slower insert/delete and more complex data management.

Comment: I dunno if it's best practice but can you just shift some of this logic to your front-end? Then, all you have to worry about is being able to store it and not a complicated query for displaying the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is so simple, it's embarrassing.
I was approaching the problem from the wrong angle, and getting stuck.
Rather than thinking of the problem as "separate checklist to then merge", it's WAY easier to see it as "one big checklist where items might be filtered out".

This way, I can simply apply the usual "one weight per field defining the records' order" (as it's always done when you have an ordered set); then, I will simply "filter out" some fields that are not applicable. The filtering can happen in a number of ways, but that's beyond the scope of my question.

Once facing the problem from the right perspective, it's becomes very simple and straightforward.